# "no cypher suites in common" java host and android client

Tags: java, android, ssl, client-server

I'm trying to get SSL communication over TCP/IP, using SSLSockets.  Once I get the SSLSocket and request the InputStream, I get the "no cypher suites in common" exception on the java (host) side, and on the client side I get: "javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x1b3da8: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error". So what I did, was list every available cypher suite on the Android side, and Enabled them on the Server side.  Still got the exact same exceptions.

Then I added the following line before getting the input streams:

```
sslSocket.setEnabledCipherSuites( sslSocket.getSupportedCipherSuites() );
```

and that worked. Obviously, I can't use that on a production environment as I'd like to ensure that secure encryption is taking place.

So what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have access to the server? Have you checked the supported ciphers on server side? What cipher suite is used if you connect to the server using your desktop browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually this indicates a misconfiguration of the server keystore. If the server cannot find a valid private key then the only ciphersuites it can use are the anonymous diffie-hellman ciphersuites. Usually these are disabled on most platforms for security reasons.

Comment: @ajacian81 the security reasons are that SSL is insecure unless at least one of the peers is authenticated. See RFC 2246 for details.

Answer (score 1):

Use  `openssl s_client -connect youserver:443` to check what protocol (TLS1, SSLv3) and cipher  (RC4-SHA, AES-SHA, etc.) is used to connect to the server. Then enable this cipher at the Android client if it is a sufficiently secure one. If it's not, make sure you enable secure cipher suites on the server. You might also want to list the `sslsocket.getEnabledCipherSuites` on the Android side to see what is available by default.

Comment: I've tried that, and added all enabled cipher suites on the android device to be used on the java server.  Still no luck.  Only that line of code posted above did the trick?

Comment: Can you connect to your server with s_client or some other program? Maybe it's not configured properly, as @GregS is saying.